# How can I check which class declares a property from a NSAttributeDescription variable?

Tags: core-data

MyClassA inherits from NSManagedObject.

MyClassB inherits from MyClassA.

MyClassA has a property, let's call it classAProp.

MyClassB has a property, let's call it classBProp.

I have an instance of MyClassB, myClassB. I want to loop through the managed attributes of this instance like this:

```
[myClassB.entity.attributesByName enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSAttributeDescription *attribute, BOOL *stop) {}]}
```

So within this block, for each attribute (classAProp, and classBProp) how can I check if MyClassA or MyClassB declared those properties.

Within the block, if I look at the [attribute description] I see something like:

```
Proxy for prop named classAProp on ed MyClassB, real (<NSAttributeDescription: 0x7fce49536be0>), name classAProp, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity MyClassA, renamingIdentifier classAProp, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 1
```

Internally it seems it's possible to access the declaring class, but I can't seem to find a way to access it myself.

Comment: I was able to access this information only through internal variable `_properties` of NSEntityDescription. That is, `[entityDescriptionB valueForKeyPath:@"_properties"]` will contain only one entry – `classBProp `. Unfortunately, using internal variables of standard frameworks are not very good for App Store, as you know of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've solved this is to create an instance of NSEntityDescription of MyClassA then check against

```
[classADescription.attributesByName.allKeys containsObject:theKey];
```

That way I can filter out properties implemented by MyClassA which was the aim.